# The char* function that I wrote doesn't seem to store values that I copied from a const char* string

Tags: c++

Below is the revised code from yesterday. It crashes on the line delete tempChar in my void function.
I tried using delete[] tempChar; making tempStr in my char* function as a global variable; and removing contents in tempChar first before delete tempChar. Neither worked.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>

char* string_reverse2(const char* string){
    cout << "the word to reverse: " << string << endl << endl;
    if (string == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    int strlength = strlen(string);
    char* tempStr = new char[strlength + 1];
    tempStr[strlength + 1] = 0;

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlength; i++){
        tempStr[index] = string[strlength - 1 - i];
        index++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return tempStr;

}

void string_reverse1(char* string){
    char* tempChar = string_reverse2(string);
    cout << tempChar << endl;
    //delete tempChar;
}

int main(){
    string_reverse1("I love Friday!");
    return 0;
}
```

==================================================================================
I take a const char* string as my parameter from my void string_reverse1 function and try to reverse it by copying the value into a newly created char* tempStr. Inside of the for-loop, I'm able to see each value of the const char* string being successfully copied over to tempStr; however, tempStr seems to be empty outside of the for-loop. Can you help me figure out what the problem is?
Thanks a lot!

```
char* string_reverse2(const char* string) {
    cout << "the word to reverse: " << string << endl << endl;
    if (string == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    int strlength = strlen(string);
    char* tempStr = new char[strlength];

    for (int i = strlen(string); i >= 0; i--){
        tempStr[strlen(string) - i] = string[i];
        cout << tempStr[strlen(string) - i];        
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    //tempStr[strlen(string) + 1] = '\0';
    cout << "reversed word: " << tempStr << endl;
    return tempStr;

}

void string_reverse1(char* string){
    const char* temp = string;
    char* tempChar = string_reverse2(temp);
    cout << tempChar;
}
```

Comment: c strings (which you are using) are 0 terminated, so their array length is 1 greater than the strlen. (Use std::string instead, you madman!)

Comment: Also, you have a memory leak. memory allocated with new should be deleted.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams _"you madman"_ Check out my avatar ;-) ...

Comment: Hint: the first character of your new string is a null terminator. You would know this if you examined it with a debugger.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: You mean their size is lenghth + terminator.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I see that I have a memory leak. How do you delete the memory in this case when I'm returning the newly create char*?

Comment: @coffeeholic as always; the way you allocated in the first place. You allocate with `new[]` , therefore you must deallocate with `delete[]`

Comment: In this case, I'm returning tempStr to the void function. If I deallocate the pointer inside of the function, an error would occur.

Comment: He means you should deallocate in the void function since all visible pointers go out of scope once the function ends the allocated memory is leaked. Really you should just use `std::string` already though.

Comment: You have a `using namespace std;` and then you happily name something `string`. To prevent confusion (or possible problems later), you should change your parameter name and drop the `using`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you could fix your code following these suggestions ([see live sample](http://ideone.com/17k8Si))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char* string_reverse2(const char* string) {
    cout << "the word to reverse: " << string << endl << endl;
    if (string == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    int strlength = strlen(string);
    char* tempStr = new char[strlength + 1];
                                    // ^^^
    // Ensure the NUL character at end of c-string
    tempStr[strlength + 1] = 0;

    int index = 0; // The inital index to fill in the reversed charactrs result
    for (int i = strlength - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                                     // ^^ Prefer the prefix increment operator 
                                     // to avoid unnecessary copies         
        tempStr[index] = string[i];
             // ^^^^^ Use this index to fill in tempStr[index]
        cout << tempStr[index]; 
        ++index;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // tempStr[strlength] = 0;
    cout << "reversed word: " << tempStr << endl;
    return tempStr;
}
```

---

```
void string_reverse1(const char* string) {
    char* tempChar = string_reverse2(string);
    cout << tempChar << endl;
    // Don't forget to finally release the memory allocated in string_reverse2()
    delete [] tempChar;
}
```

---

```
int main() {
    string_reverse1("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Output:

```
the word to reverse: Hello

olleH
reversed word: olleH
```

I've been pointing out the necessary fixes in the comments of the code sample above.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have the same code but it crashes when I'm deleting tempChar in the void function.

Comment: @coffeeholic I doubt you really have the same code then. Did you notice the link for the running live sample?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There's a bug. You allocate with `new[]` but deallocate with `delete`

Comment: @coffeeholic There was indeed a bug with the wrongly used `delete` instead of `delete []`.

Comment: Both delete and delete[] crash my program while compiling :(

Comment: @coffeeholic _"crash my program while compiling"_ Does this mean you have a compiler error? Which one exactly? [Could you add this info to your question post please.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26473452/edit) Don't change the original code you've posted please. Add another section describing what you have changed, and which is the exact compiler error you get.